# Simplify fractional exponents

Tags: arithmetic

I am aware of the following rule:
    $a^{\frac{b}{c}} = (a^b)^{\frac{1}{c}}$ AND $a^\frac{b}{c} = (a^\frac{1}{c})^b$

I have a problem as follows:
 $32^\frac{3}{5}$

I simplify it:
$(32^\frac{1}{5})^3$

The problem is it took me some time to realize what $32^\frac{1}{5}$ is because raising something to the power of 5 is not too obvious what the solution could be. Ultimately, I realized it was $2^5$ but that came with much trial and error. Are there any techniques available to help me resolve these kinds of fractional exponents quicker?

Comment: You should use parentheses.  a^b/c should be read as $(a^b)/c$, not $a^{(b/c)}$

Comment: Break it down into a smaller number. Since $32$ is even start with dividing it by $2$. $$32=2\cdot16=2\cdot(2\cdot8)=2\cdot(2\cdot2^3)=2^5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful to memorize a few powers of $2$: $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle 32=2^5, 32^{\dfrac15}=(2^5)^{\dfrac15}=2^1$

$\displaystyle\implies32^{\dfrac35}=(32^{\dfrac15})^3=\cdots$